# Rails 3: can't call an ActiveRecord query with the #send method (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In the rails console I get those results:

```
Employee.send("find_by_shop_id(2)")
NoMethodError: undefined method `find_by_shop_id(2)' for <Class:0x000000032f75d0> from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord 3.1.4/lib/active_record/base.rb:1088:in `method_missing'
```

But when I type the method directly:

```
Employee.find_by_shop_id(2)
=> #<Employee id: 2, first_name: "Roger", last_name: "Bartoletti", email: "marilie_hane@harris.biz", shop_id: 2>
```

How come the #find_by_shop_id cant be "sent" ?

Thanks

Comment: I am just wondering why would you use a finder with a `send` method

Comment: The string used in the finder is generated by itterating through an array of foreing keys.
['shop_id', 'foo_id',...].each { |foreign_key| "find_by_#{foreign_key}...

Comment: Maybe theres a better way to do what I want to do... I don't know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method you're trying to execute is called `find_by_shop_id` not `find_by_shop_id(2)`. The [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-send) method expects a method name, followed by the parameters. E.g.,

```
Employee.send "find_by_shop_id", 2
```